# What is the term for replacing a literal with a changeable symbol?

Tags: terminology

Is there a designated term for replacing hard constants (literals of any type) peppered throughout code with changeable constructs (can be a variable or #define or any similar mechanism)?

Basically, the overarching effect is integrating data into one place where one change is seen in multiple places.

**For example:**

```
int y = alpha(3);
.
.
.
if(beta(3)) x = a + b;
.
.
.
while(gamma(3)) {
    delta("hello");
}
```

becomes

```
int y = alpha(SCALE_FACTOR);
.
.
.
if(beta(SCALE_FACTOR)) x = a + b;
.
.
.
while(gamma(SCALE_FACTOR)) {
    delta(GREETING);
}
```

Comment: That is a form of abstraction.

Comment: This is also know as the "introduce a constant" or "extract constant" refactoring (it's implied that it's a named constant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no universally agreed single term for replacing a literal with a changeable symbol.

For **numeric literals** this kind of refactoring is commonly simply called:

- [replacing magic literal](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMagicLiteral.html)
- [replacing magic numbers](https://refactoring.guru/fr/replace-magic-number-with-symbolic-constant)

since everybody knows that [***magic*** numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) are difficult to maintain and are replaced with less magic but more readable [symbolic](https://wiki.c2.com/?ReplaceMagicNumberWithSymbolicConstant)/named constants.

For nor **non-numeric** literals, the term “***hard-coded***” is generally preferred to “magic”.

Strings for example, unlike numbers, have the advantage to speak for themselves (at least sometimes) and be less repetitive and easier to find and replace. There is less incentive to replace them with symbols.  Their replacement with constants is often done in the context of internationalization: the term used is “string extraction”, since all strings are then moved to a separate file and replaced with constants in the original source.

Answer (score 0):

The practice of using named constants has no name more specific than the generally applicable "don't repeat yourself".

The opposite is called *magic numbers*, and it's a well-known antipattern.